# Open, Edit and Save PDF File in C#.Net

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, pdfclown

I have a requirement to open an existing pdf file and need to add some comments or edit existing content and save the same file.

I spent so many hours on this and most people referred itextsharp or pdf clown but unfortunately didn't get any samples or how to use itextsharp or pdf clown to do the requirement.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/277065/Creating-PDF-documents-with-iTextSharp

Comment: http://simpledotnetsolutions.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/itextsharp-few-c-examples/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599897/where-can-i-find-good-examples-tutorials-for-itext-using-net

Comment: I found these after googling "itextsharp example". May I ask where you tried to find sample code for itextsharp?

Comment: Mikedotnetting website for me has a lot of examples as starter http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/80/Create-PDFs-in-ASP.NET-getting-started-with-iTextSharp

Comment: Editing PDF content, unless specified to only apply to special cases, can prove extremely difficult. Be sure to have very clear requirements and can expect sane pdfs as input.

Comment: My homegrown solution for patching the text inside PDF: https://github.com/astef/PatchPdfText

Answer (score 3):

Again mikesdotnetting website is a good starter when i made one and it works.

Here's for adding text with chunks, phrases and paragraph [example](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/82/iTextSharp-Adding-Text-with-Chunks-Phrases-and-Paragraphs)

And here's one for editing an already existing pdf file [here](http://johnnycode.com/2010/03/05/using-a-template-to-programmatically-create-pdfs-with-c-and-itextsharp/).

Comment: I would like to add though @user2218549 that you need to use a template of the pdf in order to replace the content and it's doable for free.